# Create a checkbox type li and then for looping the whole thing 3 times

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, createelement

So I am trying to do 3 things:
1- create checkboxes for the li's that are class ingredients.
2- remove that pesky li that is added after the the li calss intructions.
3- loop this whole thing 3 times so I will have 3 containers of recipes just with different images as the recipe class.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../resources/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../resources/css/flexboxgrid-6.3.1/css/flexboxgrid.min.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="../../favicon.png" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../resources/libs/jquery/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../resources/script/main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../resources/libs/bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <!--<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDoYZy2GGamOODtfAgNr3Q0q_LZAYzfBRk&callback=initMap"></script>-->
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="../../resources/script/googleMaps.js"></script>-->
    <title>Dinner Party</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="mainContainer col-md-12 col-xs-12">
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

JS

```
var main = function () {

    var $checkBoxes = document.createElement('div');
         $checkBoxes.setAttribute("class", "checkBoxes");
    var $recipePicContainer =  document.createElement('span');
         $recipePicContainer.setAttribute("class", "recipePicContainer");


    function makeRecipePic(){
        var recipe = document.createElement("IMG");
            recipe.setAttribute("src", "../images/grasshopper-cocktail.jpg");
            recipe.setAttribute("class", "recipe");
            $recipePicContainer.appendChild(recipe);

    }
    makeRecipePic();

    var mainContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('mainContainer');
        mainContainer[0].appendChild($checkBoxes);

    var $div = document.createElement('div');
        $div.innerHTML = 'CockTails';
        $recipePicContainer.appendChild($div);
        $checkBoxes.appendChild($recipePicContainer);


    var $recipes = document.createElement("ul");
    var $checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('checkBoxes');

    //var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
    //x.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");

    for (var i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
        var li = document.createElement("li","INPUT");
        li.className = "ingredients";
        li.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");

        var a = document.createElement("a");
        a.innerHTML = "Ingredient " + i;

        li.appendChild(a);
        $recipes.appendChild(li);
    }
    var b = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";
    li.className = "Instructions";
    li.appendChild(b);

    $checkboxes[0].appendChild($recipes);
    $('.recipes').hide();

    $('.mainContainer .recipePicContainer').click(function () {
        $(this).next('ul').toggle("slow").toggleClass('selected');

    });
};
$(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/DanDaManEker/z9bz4c27/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2nd step : **li.appendChild(b);**  will get rid of extra that pesky li .

and in 1st Step : Do you want checkBoxes with li options ? can you set it up on some online tool like https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Thanx for that second step. Oh and here's my fiddle...for some reason it runs nothing https://jsfiddle.net/DanDaManEker/z9bz4c27/3/

Comment: Click on external resources and include jQuery cdn link

https://jsfiddle.net/z9bz4c27/7/